# How to add new node into elasticsearch cluster on one virtual machine

Tags: elasticsearch, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have one virtual machine (Ubuntu 64bit), where is running one instance of elasticsearch (+kibana,+sense) - master node, port 9200. What I need is to add another nodes (instances of elastic search). (I am using vagrant for ssh, too.) So, how to add new data node with port 9202 and another master node with port 9201, and then how to remove old master node with port 9200.

I heard about that in old versions of elasticsearch, there were files elasticsearch.0.yml, elasticsearch.1.yml, etc. But I think that this way does not works in current version.

I guess that I need to create (*.sh) file for running yml file, but I haven't any experiences with that.

Can anyone help me? Thanks. Examples are welcome.